# SQL Alchemy : Table primary_key - unexpected keyword argument error

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, keyword

I keep getting the below error regarding the `primary_key=True` . Please could someone point out where i'm going wrong. I'm trying to follow:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#metadata-describing

```
from sqlalchemy import *

mydata123 = table("dailymarketdata", metadata, 
                    column('data_id', mysql.BIGINT, primary_key=True), 
                    column('dt', Date), 
                    column('security_id', mysql.VARCHAR), 
                    column('open', float), 
                    column('high', float), 
                    column('low', float), 
                    column('close', float), 
                    column('ma200', float), 
                    column('rtrend', mysql.TINYINT))
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-350-bd385371a391> in <module>()
  2 
  3 mydata123 = table("dailymarketdata", metadata, 
----> 4                  column('data_id', mysql.BIGINT, primary_key=True),
  5              column('dt', Date),
  6              column('security_id', mysql.VARCHAR),

TypeError: column() got an unexpected keyword argument 'primary_key'
```

If I exclude `primary_key=True` I get another error

```
`AttributeError: 'MetaData' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python is a case sensitive language

- `column` and `Column` are different callables in sqlalchemy.
- `table` and `Table` are also different callables
- `float` is the python data type, while the sqlalchemy type is `Float`

Try, rewriting your snippet as:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.dialects import *
metadata = MetaData()
mydata123 = Table("dailymarketdata", metadata, 
                  Column('data_id', mysql.BIGINT, primary_key=True), 
                  Column('dt', Date), 
                  Column('security_id', mysql.VARCHAR), 
                  Column('open', Float), 
                  Column('high', Float), 
                  Column('low', Float), 
                  Column('close', Float), 
                  Column('ma200', Float), 
                  Column('rtrend', mysql.TINYINT))
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column
.
.
.

class progect(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'progect'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Colunm is right not column

Comment: Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31766018). Your answer is already stated in the previous answer with 9 votes.